# Redefine Scanner's not-a-number recognition?

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, nan

In Java, the class `java.util.Scanner` provides a convenient way to parse long strings. In my particular case I have to parse a string with many `double` values, for which I use the `nextDouble()` method.

Sometimes, my input string contains `nan` instead of a valid float number. Unfortunately, `Scanner` only seems to recognize `NaN` for not-a-number.

Is there any way to teach it to also recognize `nan`? Maybe by setting a custom `Locale` with `DecimalFormatSymbols.setNaN()`?

Comment: why dont you just do String replace all on the input, search for nan and switch them to NaN

Comment: because it's quite a long string and this would mean parsing the whole string twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private static final Pattern nan =
        Pattern.compile("nan", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
public static boolean hasNextDouble(Scanner scanner) {
    if(scanner == null)
        return false;
    return scanner.hasNext(nan) || scanner.hasNextDouble();
}
public static double nextDouble(Scanner scanner) {
    if(scanner.hasNext(nan)) {
        scanner.next();
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    return scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as always I was thinking much too complicated. This solution is simple and from what I can see won't have a huge performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

One option is setting a custom `Locale`.  Another option is that internally the scanner uses a regular expression to retrieve a double-string and then uses `Double.parseDouble` to convert it to a `double`, so you could call `Scanner#next(Pattern pattern)` using the regular expression [defined here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) except using "nan" instead of "NaN" and then call `Double.parseDouble` on the returned string.